# Is there any way to freeze the build in Cruise Control .NET?

Tags: ccnet-config

I am using Cruise Control .NET to automate the build. I have configured lots of project for the automated build in CCNET. Is there any way to freeze particular build and after sometime, i wanna release that to old state, like i wanna remove the freeze and the user would be able to build it again.

Can i do some configuration for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the config file. The easiest way is to set the `<triggers/>` to empty. That way you can still manually force a build but the automation will stop.

```
<cruisecontrol>
   <project name="MyProject">
      <webURL>http://mybuildserver/ccnet/</webURL>
      <triggers>
      <!-- No more automated builds -->
      <!-- <intervalTrigger seconds="60" /> -->
      </triggers>
      <modificationDelaySeconds>10</modificationDelaySeconds>
```

*Update*

> This is mainly when i give a build to
>   QA for testing, and others should not
>   force buil by mistake and change the
>   build. For this reason i am looking
>   something which can freeze the build.

You shouldn't rely on having to pause the build system. The whole point of CruiseControl is to implement a continuous build system. You are breaking that model by trying to stop the builds. You should setup a pipeline for your builds:

1. Tag Build with Date and Release information. Release Candidate 0.1 Build 23423_20110602
2. Deploy a build to another machine for testing.

This way you know exactly which build the QA team is testing. And more importantly, you can go back in time in your version control system to see the code or branch.

There isn't any point having CruiseControl if the policy is to pause the build for each QA cycle. I suggest rethinking the process and coming up with a solution that doesn't involve having to stop the builds.

Comment: But still the user will be able to do a force build. So i need something where i can freeze the build(no force build/automation). This is mainly when i give a build to QA for testing, and others should not force buil by mistake and change the build. For this reason i am looking something which can freeze the build.